# MVC client validation again.

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I use ASP.NET MVC 5, and have the following code:

Layout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Main.js")"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

model:

```
public class PatientApplicationViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Home Phone Number")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid home phone")]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
```

and view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomePhone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomePhone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomePhone)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Does not work! Only on server side Model.IsValid = false. Why client side does not work and how to fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think your viewmodel HomePhone is missing the [Required] tag

It should be:

```
public class PatientApplicationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Home Phone Number")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid home phone")]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
```